# Getting “AccessDenied” while accessing S3 using Cognito Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am following the below tutorial to allow browser based upload to my `S3` bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

I finished the entire tutorial but when i submit a photo from `localhost` i get the `403` access denied with `acl` set to `public-read` and `400` with `acl` set to `public`.

My `IAM` policy is as shown there

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and I am using the unauthenticated anonymous user.

The `cognito` console is showing `unauthenticated` users but I am not getting to know why also.

The function i'm using to upload is as below

```
function uploadPDF() {

    var file = $('#fileUpload').val();
    var fileName = Date.now().toString() + ".pdf";
    var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent("files") + '/';

    var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + fileName;
    s3.upload({
        Key: photoKey,
        Body: file,
        ACL: 'public'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
        }
        alert('Successfully uploaded photo.');
    });
}
```

and i've set up the `AWS SDK` as below

```
    AWS.config.update({
            region: 'ap-south-1',
            credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId: 'ap-south-1:IdentityPoolKey'
            })
        });

        var s3 = new AWS.S3({
            apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
            params: {Bucket: albumBucketName}
        });
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899880/getting-accessdenied-while-accessing-s3-using-cognito-token) answer i tried changing the `IdentityPoolId` to `us-east-1` but it didn't show any changes.

Comment: Please do make sure that the identity pool ID looks something like this 'ap-south-1:z5f7fe0b-ff8a-4cf8-ae20-c70b682g79b5' and the region is correctly set. You can find the correct IdentityPoolId by going to Cognito > Manage Identity Pools > Federated Identities > 'some-userpool-name' > Sample code. Also make sure you are attaching the IAM role to the identites provided by Cognito.

Comment: @TenorFlyy, I am getting `Access Denied` after i copied the same creds from `Cognito` console.

Comment: Have you attached the policy to the Role created by Cognito?

Comment: Yep, I have attached the policy.

Comment: Hey, I had missed out `/*` in the policy. It's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, cool, glad you got it working ^_^ Have a nice day!

Comment: @TenorFlyy, Thanks. you too :)